# Are the interaction terms in these two models equivalent?

Tags: regression, interaction, model, linear

I am trying to understand if the outcome of one model is equivalent to another.

So for instance, I have three variables: wealth (continuous in dollars), productive (dichotomous: yes or no) and age_group (categorical: young,mid,old).

First model: wealth~productive*age_group
Second model: productive~wealth*age_group

So the interaction term in my first model represents whether the relationship between productive and wealth is age_group dependent and the interaction of second model represents whether the relationship between wealth and productive is age_group dependent.

Are these two interaction terms explaining the same thing?

**Update:** I am doing this in R:

- First model: lmmodel <- lm(wealth~productive*age_group)
- Second model: glmmodel <- glm(productive~wealth*age_group,family=binomial(link='logit'‌​),na.action=na.omit)

Comment: Can you say a little more about the modeling approach you are using?

Comment: @WillieWheeler I am doing this in R:  First model: `lmmodel <- lm(wealth~productive*age_group)`  Second model: `glmmodel <- glm(productive~wealth*age_group,family=binomial(link='logit'),na.action=na.omit)`

Comment: These are *totally different* models because the response variables switch roles with the regressor variables.  They "explain" completely different things!  What, then, do you mean by an "outcome" of a model and what form of "equivalent" do you have in mind?

Comment: What I mean by outcome is, if I run the first model and determine that the effect of productive on wealth is age group contextual (I.e a significant interaction term), can I then conclude that the effect of wealth on productive is age group contextual?